# How to getting the certificate directly from the WinStore in bytes to send to the request?

Tags: python, windows, python-requests, client-certificates, httpx

I have an API which accepts certificate signed requests.
At the moment I do it this way
`response = requests.post(some_url, data=some_data, cert=path_to_cert)`

For security reasons, I was obliged not to use a downloaded certificate from the vindows storage and to send requests from memory.

**Are you aware of libraries or requests adapters that can receive str in the cert argument?**

i try to do this code but got stuck at the point of send str/bytes into request

```
cert_name = "NAME CERT IN CERT STORE"


def export_cert_to_pem(cert, pem_path)->str:
    pem = cert.get_pem()

    return pem

def find_cert_in_trusted_roots(cert_name:str):
    for storename in ("CA", "ROOT"):
        with wincertstore.CertSystemStore(storename) as store:
            for cert in store.itercerts(usage=wincertstore.SERVER_AUTH):
                if cert.get_name().lower() == cert_name.lower():
                    export_cert_to_pem(cert, cert_name + ".pem")

                    # export_cert_to_pem(cert, pem_path)
                    return 1

    return 0


cert = find_cert_in_trusted_roots(cert_name)
```

**#here is not work , cert must be a path**
`response = requests.post(some_url, data=your_data, cert=cert)`

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. You cannot read your cert as a byte string, then pass that string to `requests`.  Here is why:

The `requests` package uses the `urllib3.poolmanager.PoolManager` to establish a connection and send a request. The `urllib3.poolmanager.PoolManager.urlopen()` method accepts a `cert` parameter.

This `urlopen()` method is handled by a `urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection` object if connecting to a `https://...` url, which you would be doing if you are passing a client certificate.

The `urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection` object wrap the connection's socket with SSL/TLS using a `ssl.SSLContext` object.

The `ssl.SSLContext` object loads a client certificate using the `ssl.SSLContext.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile)` method.  This method is actually implemented in C, you can see it [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_ssl.c#L3847).  What is important is that it calls `SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file()` to load the certificate into the SSL context.  This reads the file from disk, which means it MUST be a file on disk and not a byte string.